# Defining attribute assertions on xs:anyTipe elements in xsd 1.1

Tags: xml, xsd

I have to define first of all a sequence of anytype elements. My situation is the following:

```
<staticAction name="Jump" >
    <"anyElementName" reqPoints="" gainedPoints="" />
    <"anyElementName" reqPoints="" gainedPoints="" />
    <"anyElementName" reqPoints="" gainedPoints="" />
    ...
</staticAction>
```

So, my question is: how can I define an unbounded sequence of elements with "dynamic" names but with fixed attributes (reqPoints and gainedPoints) ? Both attributes are xs:integer. I thought about adding the attributes through assertations but still, I don't know exactly how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to use xpath assertions for this you need to specify many things: every element has reqPoints and gainedPoints attributes, both attributes are numbers, there are only two attributes and no more, the element doesn't have content, etc...  Take a look at this notation that you can use in asserts: `every $element in ./* satisfies ($element[@reqPoints and @gainedPoints and count(@*=2) and etc])` This is easier to do in XSD as it is so much more expressive, the problem is the dynamic names, do you really need them?

Comment: @sergioFC Unfortunately I really need the elements to be Dynamic. I am not an expert in assertions and xsd in general.. may you please post some code with both the definition of the dynamic elements by using xs:anyType or xs:any and the assertions for the corresponding attributes? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually *"dynamic"* names can be replaced so they can be modelated using XSD. Example:

From

```
<places>
    <country value="x"/>
    <city value="y"/>
    <town value="z"/>
</places>
```

To

```
<places>
    <place type="country" value="x"/>
    <place type="city" value="y"/>
    <place type="town" value="z"/>
</places>
```

In this new case only attribute values are *"dynamic"*. This is suitable for being modeled using XSD, which is easier and more expressive than XPath assertions.

However, if you really need to validate that *"dynamic"* names with known attributes and content type you can see this sample schema with assertions (explained inside the schema):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    vc:minVersion="1.1" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning">
    <xs:element name="staticAction">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <!-- Base is anyType -->
                <xs:extension base="xs:anyType">
                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                    <!-- Check that every "dynamic" child has the two integer attributes and no other attributes -->
                    <xs:assert test="every $element in ./* satisfies 
                        ($element[
                            matches(@reqPoints, '^[+-]?\d+$') and
                            matches(@gainedPoints, '^[+-]?\d+$') and
                            count(@*=2)])"/>
                    <!-- Test that there is no content in staticAction nor in the "dynamic" nodes -->
                    <xs:assert test="matches(string(.), '^\s*$')"/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Note that by extending *xs:anyType* and using that assertions you are getting an unbounded sequence of elements with any name and those two attributes.

Comment: That's working! Thanks once more :) I already accepted it as answer but I would like to ask you something more if possible: I declare these StaticActions at the beginning of my xml file by using a simple xs:sequence because I need exactly 3 of those and in a certain order. There, I want to make sure that these 3 staticActions have proper names (through the "name" attribute that you specified in your solution): "Jump" "Greetings" and "Eat" . So I need to check that in my XML all the 3 of them "Jump", "Greetings" and "Eat" are there, through a simple assertion. May you help me please?

Comment: @Tarta Of course, you can assert `/root/staticAction[1]='Jump' and /root/staticAction[2]=...` etc.  The language used in assertions is XPath, if you want you can read this good and simple [XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) that shows the basics of XPath that you can use in assertions.

Comment: mmm somehow it doesn't work.. I tried to apply it in the way you wrote it but it seems not working. And the link you gave me it is offline at the moment haha (lucky eh? :) ) I wrote another question containing this point so maybe it's easier answering there than doing it here through comments .. it is the point number 2 of the question at this link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896717/defining-assertions-depending-on-both-attributes-and-elements-in-xsd-1-1)
If you can help me also with the point 1 I make you a statue because I would be almost done with my project :)