# Defining assertions depending on both attributes and elements in xsd 1.1

Tags: xml, xsd

I need to define the following situation in my XSD Schema. This is an example of my XML:

```
<initialization>

  <stat name="SelfActualization" range="" init="" tickValue="" colorR="" colorG="" colorB=""/>
  <stat name="Social" range="" init="" tickValue="" colorR="" colorG="" colorB=""/>

  <staticAction name="Study" >
    <SelfActualization reqPoints="0" gainedPoints="0" />
    <Social reqPoints="0" gainedPoints="0" />
  </staticAction>

  <staticAction name="Greetings" >
    <SelfActualization reqPoints="0" gainedPoints="0" />
    <Social reqPoints="0" gainedPoints="0" />
  </staticAction>

  <staticAction name="Eat" >
    <SelfActualization reqPoints="0" gainedPoints="0" />
    <Social reqPoints="0" gainedPoints="0" />
  </staticAction>

</initialization>
```

1st assertation that I need: I can define as many "stat" elements as I want (in this case only 2) and I already managed to obtain this behavior. What I don't know how to do is: in any of my "StaticActions" I need that all the "stats" previously defined above are  named again (as elements, this is something I already do through the xs:anyType element but I need an assertation which controls that the names correspond), AND in the same order they have been defined at the beginning.
As we can see in the example indeed both "SelfActualization" and "Social" are there and in the right order in all my StaticActions. If another "stat" not defined before, or if one of the "stats" defined is missing, or if the order is wrong, the XML has to be refused. My XSD looks like this so far:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="initialization" type="initializationType" />

<xs:complexType name="initializationType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="stat"/>
    <xs:element  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="staticAction"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="staticAction" type="StaticActionType"/>

<xs:complexType name="StaticActionType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <!-- Base is anyType -->
        <xs:extension base="xs:anyType">
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <!-- Check that every "dynamic" child has the two integer attributes and no other attributes -->
            <xs:assert test="every $element in ./* satisfies 
                ($element[
                    matches(@reqPoints, '^[+-]?\d+$') and
                    matches(@gainedPoints, '^[+-]?\d+$') and
                    count(@*=2)])"/>
            <!-- Test that there is no content in staticAction nor in the "dynamic" nodes -->
            <xs:assert test="matches(string(.), '^\s*$')"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

2nd assertation that I need: I declare the StaticActions at the beginning of my xsd schema by using a simple xs:sequence because I need exactly a certain number of those and in a certain order. There, I want to make sure that these staticActions have proper names (through the "name" attribute specified in the staticAction definition): for example I want "Study" "Greetings" and "Eat" . So I need to check that in my XML all the 3 of them "Study", "Greetings" and "Eat" are there, through a simple assertion.

EDIT: Last point is: My staticAction needs to contain 2 static elements as well besides the dynamic ones like shown in the following example:

```
<initialization>

  <stat name="SelfActualization" range="" init="" tickValue="" colorR="" colorG="" colorB=""/>
  <stat name="Social" range="" init="" tickValue="" colorR="" colorG="" colorB=""/>

  <staticAction name="Study" >
    <SelfActualization reqPoints="0" gainedPoints="0" />
    <Social reqPoints="0" gainedPoints="0" />

    <RequiredAction action="string" cardinality="int" />
    <SuccessLikelihood likelihood="int" />
  </staticAction>
```

Therefore I need to modify my definition of the "StaticAction" and modify some of the assertions that checks all of the childs of staticAction.

Comment: The second requeriment is not clear. Do you need all of the elements to have any of that names, can a name be repeated, is order important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first requeriment you can use the following assertion inside *initializationType*:

```
<xs:assert test="every $staticAction in ./staticAction satisfies deep-equal(data($staticAction/*/name()), data(./stat/@name)) "/>
```

This ensures that every `staticAction` contains childs with node names equal to the attribute name of the `stat` elements in the same order.

For the second requirement you can use this simple assertion supposing that order is not important and that values can be repeated:

```
<xs:assert test="every $staticAction in ./staticAction satisfies $staticAction/@name = ('Study', 'Greetings', 'Eat') "/>
```

This can also be modelated in XSD:

```
<xs:attribute name="name">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Study"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Greetings"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Eat"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

Otherwise, if values cannot be repeated but must appear you can use three diferent assertions to ensure that every value exsists one time (e.g: `count(./staticAction[@name='Eat']) = 1`).

Comment: It's perfect! The first option works perfectly and for the second requirement I just needed to use both the assertions you proposed cause I both wanted to specify that it is not possible to declare other staticActions than the ones I say and those that I want cannot be repeated but MUST appear. Man, once more, your help is changing the results of my project.. really THANK YOU!

Comment: One little thing: what about if in your definition of the staticAction after the "anyType" elements I want to add a couple of fixed elements? They have to be in a xs:sequence but they are really simple elements that I just need to be there. The question is: where should I place the xs:sequence in that definition?

Comment: Probably you would need to define the complexType as a sequence that contains your known elements and a <xs:any> with maxOccurs. If this elements (the known and the dynamics ones) are "brothers" (as I understand) you would need to change some of the assertions that checks all of the childs of staticAction.

Comment: oh damn it, I thought it was easier, that's why I didn't insert it in this question. I was sure it wouldn't have been a problem. Should I create a new question then or edit this one?

Comment: just EDITED the question with a 3rd point but if you want me to create another question (which will be similar to this one) I will do it without any problem!

Comment: @Tarta I think its better if you start a chat and revert the question changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80838/discussion-between-sergiofc-and-tarta).

Comment: something seems not working yet.. I made everything clear and clean in this  [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914025/defining-assertion-depending-on-elements-in-xsd-1-1) whenever you are still willing to help and have time to do it :) Thanks in advance!